# SSO - Many-To-One recommendation

Tags: single-sign-on, broker

for an application which offers the integration of one SSO solution, we need to add multiple SSO "providers".
One connection which authorizes the employees working in our company and multiple others which authorize each of our customers, which should have access.

Is there any self-hosted or saas solution providing something like that?

As I understood the identity broker services I had a look at, they provide a solution as *Many-To-One*.

I would like to find a service, which works as a broker between the application and different sso sources (e.g. AzureAD, local AD, LDAP, ...).

Comment: checkout https://datawiza.com

Answer (score 0):

There are a few services available as far as I know.

1. WorkOS
2. SAML Jackson from BoxyHQ (Open-source and Self hosted)
3. Datawiza

The above services support multiple IdPs such as Okta, OneLogin, Azure AD, JumpCloud, etc.